# How to check if url contains something?

Tags: angular

i have url something like this : `loltest12.com/test` and `loldev12.com`.
How can i check if it have lol and 12 and return true?

I tried this:

```
local = this.router.url.indexOf('loltest12') || this.router.url.indexOf('loldev12');
```

Comment: is that a javascript question?

Comment: what is your question. can you rephrase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean the javascript function string.include, which return true or false.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp

The function indexOf just returns a number between -1 and "the length of the string"-1.

=>

```
local = this.router.url.includes('loltest12') || this.router.url.includes('loldev12');
```

Comment: is it possible to to something includes lol +whatever +12 not to write two times included

Comment: You can do a regular Expression check. But that works in a different way. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: const regEx = /.*?lol.*?12.*/;           let result = regEx.test(myString);

Comment: This regEx would match for instance: 'blablaloltest12.com/test' and 'loltest12.com/test' and 'loldev12.com'

Answer (score 1):

You have the `match` function for that. See how it behaves :

```js
const url = 'loltest12.com/test';
alert(url.match(/^lol\w*12.*$/));
alert(url.match(/^notlol\w*12.*$/));
```

This Regex says

> Find every url that is starting **(^)** with lol **(lol)**, which then have any number of alphanumerical characters **(\w*)**, then 12 **(12)**, and ends with any other characters **(./$)**

Comment: i have loltest12 and loldev12 but i want to check if i have lol and whatever in midle and on last place 12

Comment: Do you want to store the value that you have between lol and 12 ?

Comment: i will have a lot of them loltest344 loltest2423 i want if i have only lol and on end 12